# SQL Query to get dates of X days after current date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

How can i construct a query that would return some 'x' number of dates after the current date (`sysdate`)?

For example if today is `18-May-2018` and I ask for `x=2`, then I should get

19-May-2018

20-May-2018

as the output.

Comment: What is your `RDBMS`? PostgreSql has no `sysdate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `generate_series`.

```
SELECT generate_series(current_date + 1, 
                       current_date + 2, 
                       interval '1' day)
```

[**Docs**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-srf.html)

In plsql, you may set `x` as variable and then use it in your query.

```
knayak=# \set x 5
knayak=# SELECT generate_series(current_date + 1,                                                                                                            
                                current_date + :x,                                                                                                                        
                                interval '1' day);

 generate_series      
---------------------------
 2018-05-19 00:00:00+05:30
 2018-05-20 00:00:00+05:30
 2018-05-21 00:00:00+05:30
 2018-05-22 00:00:00+05:30
 2018-05-23 00:00:00+05:30
```

You may format the dates in desired format with `TO_CHAR`

```
SELECT  to_char(dt,'DD-MON-YYYY') as dates
FROM    generate_series(current_date + 1, 
                        current_date + 2, 
                        interval '1' day) as dt

dates    
-------------
19-MAY-2018
20-MAY-2018
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PostgreSQL, you could use this:

```
SELECT current_date + s.a AS dates 
FROM generate_series(1, 2, 1) AS s(a);
```

And change 2 to value of your `x`

Answer (score 1):

since you have written `sysdate,` I believe you are looking for an **oracle** database, if you are looking for an oracle database please use the following statement

```
select  trunc(sysdate)+level ldate from dual
connect by level <&x;
```

above query will ask for x, when you give the value of x as 3, it will generate two days from sysdate